# Custom Email Marketing from Django on Slicehost Server

Tags: django, email, slicehost

I have a Slicehost slice running django through nginx and apache. This is for a project in which email marketing is a key component. We will need to be able to send up to 10,000 emails in a day from this Django app. We need to recieve email as well, however, that can simply be a forwarder.

What would be your recommended solution? would you setup a postfix mail server on the slice or try to use some 3rd party mail service with an API like MailChimp or constant contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending thousands of emails from your own machine in a reliable way is very hard.

I would recommend you to use [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/). You can use them as a smtp server, so there's no need to code against APIs. They can also receive email and POST the data to a URL on your server.